# How can I find all possible values of x:Name for VisualState for all controls

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

When I create my own Control Template I can describe different views of controls using VisualState tag:

```
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
           <Storyboard>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
           </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
```

Where can I find all possible values for x:Name ? It is the same list for all TargetType of Control Template or there is a different possible x:Name's for each TargetType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is control dependent.

You need to either check the documentation (the Windows.UI.Xaml controls have pages such as [Button styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709909.aspx). There are similar pages for WPF), you can look up the source for the template (Windows.UI.Xaml controls are in Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\xaml\design\generic.xaml ) or you can generate a copy of the template from the designer by selecting the control, right clicking to get the context menu, and picking Edit Template...

If you're creating your own control then you can define the visual states however you'd like.